# How can I compare console output with excel sheet data using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I have retrieved the elements of a table to the console window and I would like to compare the output with data present in an excel sheet. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
// To locate table.
    WebElement mytable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\ejSearchResultTable\"]"));
    // To locate rows of table.
    List<WebElement> rows_table = mytable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    // To calculate no of rows In table.
    int rows_count = rows_table.size();
    // Loop will execute till the last row of table.
    for (int row = 0; row < rows_count; row++) {
        // To locate columns(cells) of that specific row.
        List<WebElement> Columns_row = rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        // To calculate no of columns (cells). In that specific row.
        int columns_count = Columns_row.size();
        System.out.println("Number of cells In Row " + row + " are " + columns_count);
        // Loop will execute till the last cell of that specific row.
        for (int column = 0; column < columns_count; column++) {
            // To retrieve text from that specific cell.
            String celtext = Columns_row.get(column).getText();
            System.out
                    .println("Cell Value of row number " + row + " and column number " + column + " Is " + celtext);
        }

    }
```

Reading data from Excel:

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ExportExcel.xlsx";  
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);  
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);  
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);  
for (int i=0; i<Rowcount+1 ; i++)
{
Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++)
{
System.out.println("Cell Value of row number " + i + " and column number " + j+ " Is " + row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
        }
```

Comment: how are you printing that on console ? is it sysout  ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes or do you have any other approach to compare the elements of web table with data in the excel sheet? Thanks

Comment: yes there are ways. Can you share some code how are you doing sysout, are you storing anything in an variable ?

Comment: hey @cruisepandey I have added code to the description section. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Is it `celtext ` you want to verify ? Do you have a utility method to read values from excel. Basically, from UI we will retrieve actual value and from excel we can retrieve expected value,  and using testng we can do AssertEquals to verify both the strings.

Comment: @cruisepandey I am able to read data from Excel but the output from UI and excel sheet are coming in different format/structure. The data from UI comes row wise where as excel sheet output comes cell wise in multiple line, Attached the code from Read excel as well, Could you please help me in formatting the output so that it will be possible to compare both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234548/discussion-between-ankitkumarsahoo-and-cruisepandey).